# Mac M1 React Native - IOS Pod install fails and ruby cant find the desired version

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods, rbenv, ruby-build

In my React native app, when i try `pod install` i get a ruby
version not found error.

```
benv: version `3.1.4' is not installed
```

when running `rbenv install 3.1.4`

It throws this error

```
ruby-build: definition not found: 3.1.4

See all available versions with `rbenv install --list'.

If the version you need is missing, try upgrading ruby-build:

  brew upgrade ruby-build
```

During my searches i found this thread.
https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1509